# (Java) Erro ao continuar percorrendo linhas do TXT

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, lógica, programação-estruturada

boa noite!

Preciso que mesmo que atinja a condição `total_min < 720` ele continue a percorrer as linhas. O 720 são o total de minutos antes do almoço, quando atingido deve separa as atividades que deverão ser executadas após o almoço.

- Preciso fazer um sistema que lê um arquivo TXT(intput.txt).
- Esse arquivo possui várias linhas.
- Cada linha uma atividade com tempo de execução (30min, 45min, 60min)
- As atividades deve começar às 9 horas.
- Meio dia (12:00) intervalo de almoço
- Gerar um TXT com as atividades organizadas (output.txt)

> intput.txt

```
Correr 60min
Estudar 30min
Ler 45min
Escrever 60min
Caminhar 45min
Jogar 30min
```

> Exemplo como deve ser o arquivo output.txt

```
09:00 Correr 60min
10:00 Estudar 30min
10:30 Ler 45min
11:15 Caminhar 45min
12:00 Almoço 60min
13:00 Jogar
(...)
```

> Meu código:

```
  static int i = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    ArrayList<String> antes_almoco = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> depois_almoco = new ArrayList<String>();


    int total_min = 540;
    int horas = total_min / 60;
    int minutos = total_min % 60;


    String trinta = "30min";
    String quarentaCinco = "45min";
    String sessenta = "60min";
    boolean trinta_min = false;
    boolean quarentaCinco_min = false;
    boolean sessenta_min = false;

    String nomePc = System.getProperty("user.name");
    String path = "\\input.txt";
    String outputDir = "\\output.txt";

    FileReader arq = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
    String linha;

    //Output   
    File file2 = new File(outputDir);
    FileWriter arq_output = new FileWriter(file2, true);
    PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq_output);

    if (!file2.exists()) {
        file2.createNewFile();
    }

    while ((linha = lerArq.readLine()) != null) {



            trinta_min = linha.toLowerCase().contains(trinta.toLowerCase());
            quarentaCinco_min = linha.toLowerCase().contains(quarentaCinco.toLowerCase());
            sessenta_min = linha.toLowerCase().contains(sessenta.toLowerCase());

            if (sessenta_min == true && total_min < 720) {
                total_min += 60;
                antes_almoco.add(linha);
            }

            if (trinta_min == true && total_min < 720) {
                total_min += 30;
                antes_almoco.add(linha);
            }

            if (quarentaCinco_min == true && total_min < 720) {
                total_min += 45;
                antes_almoco.add(linha);
            }

            if (total_min == 720) {
                total_min += 60;
                antes_almoco.add("12:00 Almoço");
            }


    }



    for (String cont : antes_almoco) {
        System.out.println(cont);
        gravarArq.printf("%d:%02d %s \n", horas, minutos, cont);
    }

    for (String cont : depois_almoco) {
        System.out.println(cont);
        gravarArq.printf("%d:%02d %s \n", horas, minutos, cont);
    }

    lerArq.close();
    gravarArq.close();
    arq.close();
}
```

Comment: Agora o teste de nulo no `if` ficou desnecessário kkk.

Comment: Obrigado @piovezan! Removi e deu certo. Pode me ajudar com o resto código?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Está assim: "Leia meu código e me ajude com a lógica". Seja mais específico no que você quer. Detalhe melhor.

Comment: Preciso que mesmo que atinja a condição `total_min < 720` ele continue a percorrer as linhas. O 720 são o total de minutos antes do almoço, quando atingido deve separa as atividades que deverão ser executadas após o almoço. Desculpa, sou iniciante e não consegui pensar em outra forma de fazer :(

Comment: Sem problemas. Edite a pergunta colocando esse detalhamento nela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se isso faz sentido para você.

Remova a condição `total_min < 720` do if e no lugar de `antes_almoco.add(linha)` coloque:

```
if (total_min < 720) {
    antes_almoco.add(linha);
} else if (total_min > 720) {
    depois_almoco.add(linha);
}
```

Sugiro encapsular esse trecho em uma função para reaproveitamento no código.

Comment: Aqui a gente não faz revisão de código nesses moldes (revisar uma lógica genérica), mas um lugar que você pode levar seu código para avaliação de uma melhor forma de fazer é no https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Muito obrigado! Perfeito, vou verificar!